# Tracking form submission via a thank you page, only if it contains specific text

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, conversions

I have two forms on a website. Both redirect to a "thank you" page once they are submitted. The problem is that the thank-you page is also shown if the form contains errors, which means that the same thank-you URL can be either a successful submission OR a form fail...

The good news is that if the form had been successfully submitted, there's an actual "Thank you" message displayed.

How would I set up a Form Submitted conversion in GTM and GA4 in this case? Would "Element Visibility" trigger work here (conversion would mean: a pageview of the form thank-you page AND the "thank you" text visible on the page)?

Answer (score 1):

You would be better of doing this is you write a script that fires a [custom event in GA4](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/12229021?hl=en) and then mark that [event as a conversion](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/12966437?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to modify your code, you could

1. Have two separate pages
2. Have one `thank-you` page but with params indicating success or failure.  You can then track the two urls separately.